# need advice with loop in bash function

Tags: bash, loops, centos

I'm trying to write a script to check several functions return and in case of return 1 write in the log file and send me an email, but loop is not working as expected:

1. In case of success print everything good
2. In case update fails it writes in log two lines "failed" and "done" and sends me an email.

Could you please help to find a mistake?

```
w2log() {
if [[ $? = 0 ]] ; then
   echo "=== Everything looks good ! DONE `date` ==="  >> $LOG;
else
   echo "=== Something went wrong ! FAILED `date` ==="  >> $LOG && errmail
fi
}

updaterepos() {
   syn6332
   syn5864
   for repo in syn6332 syn5864; do
      w2log
   done
}

updaterepos
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like that (if you want a `w2log` report for each command):

```
updaterepos() {
    for repo in syn6364 syn5864 ; do
        $repo
        w2log
    done
}
```

The function checking `$?` should be called immediately after the command returning the status. Function calls also set `$?` -- that's why you were getting the second "done" line when you called `w2log` second time.

Comment: Thank you ! That was so simple )